# Overview of Schelling's philosophy

Tags: schelling

I am having a hard time understanding Schelling. What should I read in order to make this experience not as nonsensical as it currently is? Is there any overview of his philosophy that will systematically show the flow of his arguments?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the post what you are currently reading, why it is not working, or what level of detail you are interested in. You can try reading [SEP's article on Schelling](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schelling) first, it also has references to more detailed sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good reads on the topic are:

1. "German Idealism" by Frederick C. Beiser.
2. "The Genesis of Neo-Kantianism" by Frederick C. Beiser.

Note, however, that these concern a reinterpretation of neo-Kantianism in general, including other relevant philosophers of the time, which helps to create context besides explicitly discussing Schelling's philosophy. It isn't the traditional reading - though the traditional reading is usually clearly stated so that it may be argued against. Michael Friedman has also written a lot on this new interpretation (and is arguably the central figure therein). A Cambridge Companion never does much harm and is useful if you want to read the above given books as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a difficult time picking literature for bettering their understanding of Schelling, I have found 1) Cambridge's companion to German idealism, and 2) Interpreting Schelling - Critical essays. These two books have greatly helped me out. I'll drop a download link [here](http://www.filedropper.com/phil).